# jQuery(this).val().trim is undefined

Tags: jquery, wordpress

What could be causing the subject error to be thrown?

I am working on a Wordpress plugin that I was not the original author of.  The plugin was sold and I am trying to assist the new owner (non-developer) in updating the plugin.

The plugin has an option for a multilist type profile field extension.  However, the field was not being displayed on the registration page because the code was absent from the registration section.  I have since added the code to display this field on the registration page and it appears to work, until the Register button is clicked.

The problem is that if any of the multilist items are selected, the subject error gets thrown and the registration does not happen.  As long as that field has no selections, there is no error and the registration occurs.

Not knowing exactly what is occurring I figured I would throw in a console.log() call to display the 'this' variable to see if I can detect any errors.  That doesn't prove to help.  Is this error caused by mismatched data types?  I'm kind of out of my element here working with jQuery and objects.  I'm trying to learn as quickly as possible, but this one is stumping me.

Here's the PHP code snippet:

```
//Multilist type field
if ($extension->wps_extension_type == 'multilist'):
   $values = explode(',', get_post_meta($extension->ID, 'wps_extension_default', true));
      $selected = $current ? $current : array();
      $item_html .= '<div class="wps_registration_field"><select id="'.$key.'" rel="'.$extension->ID.'" class="wps_registration_value wps_registration_multilist'.$mand.'" multiple="multiple" data-key="'.$key.'" size="'.sizeof($values).'" style="width: 400px;">';
   $all_values = explode(',', get_post_meta($extension->ID, 'wps_extension_default', true));
   if ($all_values):
      foreach($all_values as $value):
         $item_html .= '<option id="'.$key.'" rel="'.$extension->ID.'" class="wps_registration_value" value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
      endforeach;
   endif;
   $item_html .= '</select></div>';
   if ($mand) $item_html .= $mandatory;
endif;
```

Here's is the code snippet for jQuery:

```
// Registration
jQuery("#wps_register_submit").click(function (event) {
    if (jQuery('#wps_registration_dummy_field').val() == '') {
        jQuery('#wps_register_error').hide();

        // Check for mandatory fields
        var found = false;
        var my_var = jQuery(this).val();
        console.log('This value: ' + JSON.stringify(my_var));
        jQuery('.wps_register_mandatory').removeClass('wps_field_error');
        jQuery('.wps_register_mandatory').each(function(i, obj) {
            if (jQuery(this).css('display') != 'none' && jQuery(this).attr('id').substr(0, 4) != 's2id' && jQuery(this).val() == '') {
                jQuery(this).fadeOut().fadeIn().addClass('wps_field_error');
                found = true;
            }
            if (jQuery(this).val() !== null) {
                var my_var = jQuery(this).val();
                console.log('This value: ' + JSON.stringify(my_var));
                if (jQuery(this).val().trim() == '') {
                    if (jQuery('#s2id_'+jQuery(this).attr('id')).length > 0) {
                        jQuery('#s2id_'+jQuery(this).attr('id')).addClass('wps_field_error');
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        if (found) {
            // Missing mandatory fields
        } else {
            jQuery("body").addClass("wps_wait_loading");
            jQuery("#wps_register_submit").attr("disabled", true);

            // Get any profile extensions
            var exts = [];
            jQuery('.wps_registration_value').each(function(i, obj) {
                var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
                if (id != undefined) {
                    var value = jQuery(this).val();
                    if (value) {
                        var ext = {};
                        ext['key'] = jQuery(this).data('key'),
                        ext['id'] = id;
                        ext['value'] = value;
                        exts.push(ext);
                    }
                }
            });
            var wps_reg_code = '';
            if (jQuery('#wps_reg_code').length) {
                wps_reg_code = jQuery('#wps_reg_code').val();
            }
            jQuery.post( wps_login_ajax.ajaxurl, {
                action : 'wps_register_check',
                username : jQuery('#wps_register_username').val(),
                email : jQuery('#wps_register_email').val(),
                email2 : jQuery('#wps_register_email2').val(),
                first_name : jQuery('#wps_register_firstname').val(),
                last_name : jQuery('#wps_register_familyname').val(),
                nickname : jQuery('#wps_register_nickname').val(),
                display_name : jQuery('#wps_register_display_name').val(),
                captcha : jQuery('#wps_captcha_form').val(),
                wps_reg_code : wps_reg_code,
                wpspro_home : jQuery('#wps_register_wpspro_home').val(),
                wpspro_country : jQuery('#wps_register_wpspro_country').val(),
                password : jQuery('#wps_register_password').val(),
                password_confirm : jQuery('#wps_register_password_confirm').val(),
                registration_url : jQuery('#wps_registration_url').val(),
                register_auto : jQuery('#register_auto').val(),
                exts: exts,
                },
                function(response) {
                    jQuery("#wps_register_submit").attr("disabled", false);
                    if (response.substr(0, 2) != 'OK' && response.substr(0, 3) != 'URL') {
                        jQuery("body").removeClass("wps_wait_loading");
                        // Error, show message
                        jQuery('#wps_register_error').removeClass('wps_success').addClass('wps_error');
                        jQuery('#wps_register_error').html(response).slideDown('fast');
                    } else {
                        if (response.substr(0, 3) == 'URL') {
                            // Success, redirect if need be
                            window.location = response.substring(3);
                        } else {
                            jQuery("body").removeClass("wps_wait_loading");
                            // Success, show message
                            jQuery('#wps_register_username').val('');
                            jQuery('#wps_register_email').val('');
                            jQuery('#wps_register_email2').val('');
                            jQuery('#wps_register_firstname').val('');
                            jQuery('#wps_register_familyname').val('');
                            jQuery('#wps_register_error').removeClass('wps_error').addClass('wps_success');
                            jQuery('.wps_registration_row').hide();
                            jQuery('.wps_registration_item').hide();
                            jQuery("#wps_register_submit").hide();
                            jQuery('#wps_register_error').html(response.substring(2)).slideDown('fast');
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }

});
```

You can view this in action on my staging site at http://stage.alkpositive.org/login/.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: what's the point of the `if (jQuery('#wps_registration_dummy_field').val() == '') { ... }` wrapped around everything?

Comment: The dummy field is to catch spambots from registering on the site.  It isn't visible to a user, but a spambot will see the field and enter data into it from what I can tell from the comments in the code.